# Object Lifetime and undefined behavior

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, object-lifetime

In the 3.8 Object lifetime, there is the following section

> Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage
> which the object will occupy has been allocated40 or, after the
> lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the
> object occupied is reused or released, any pointer that refers to the
> storage location where the object will be or was located may be used
> but only in limited ways. For an object under construction or
> destruction, see 12.7. Otherwise, such a pointer refers to allocated
> storage (3.7.4.2), and using the pointer as if the pointer were of
> type void*, is well-deﬁned. Indirection through such a pointer is
> permitted but the resulting lvalue may only be used in limited ways,
> as described below. The program has undeﬁned behavior if:

> the pointer is used to access a non-static data member or call a
> non-static member function of the object,

Can anyone provide an example that explains the above statement?

Comment: Perhaps an object allocated with `malloc` (rather than `new`)?  Storage has then been allocated but no object actually exists as the constructor has not been called.

Comment: Or a byte array (of the appropriate size and alignment). Beware of the [implicit lifetime types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some examples (there are many other ways):

```
struct A {
    void f() {};
};

int main() {
    A a = ((&a)->f(), A{}); //1
    a.~A();
    (&a)->f(); //2

    A b = (*&b, A{}); //3
    b.~A();
    (*&b, 0); //4
}
```

In all four labeled cases the pointer formed with `&` and dereferenced is not an *invalid*, because these evaluations happen during the storage duration of the `a` and `b` object.

But in `//1` the call to `f` is made before the initialization of `a` is complete, meaning before its lifetime begins, and before its constructor starts, so that the quoted paragraph applies.

And in `//2` the call to `f` is made after the destructor of `a` was called, meaning that its lifetime has already ended, so that the quoted paragraph also applies.

So both `//1` and `//2` have undefined behavior.

Contrary, `//3` and `//4` are fine. They form and dereference a pointer outside the lifetime, but do not run afoul of any of the rules in [basic.life] for glvalues, after the paragraph you quoted. In particular no access to a scalar is performed, nor is a non-static member accessed.

---

However, the quoted restriction is probably redundant with the later restrictiona on use of glvalues outside of lifetime, which also forbid calling non-static member functions or accessing non-static data members. But the only way to do any of that through a pointer is to first dereference the pointer to get a glvalue anyway. (That's what `*` and `->` are defined to do.)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example with comments:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    void* storage = std::malloc(sizeof(std::string));
    
    // Before the lifetime of the object has started but after the
    // storage which the object will occupy has been allocated

    // starting the lifetime of the object:
    std::string* a_string_ptr = new(storage) std::string;

    *a_string_ptr = "Hello world, what is going on?";
    std::cout << *a_string_ptr << '\n';

    // ending the lifetime of the object
    a_string_ptr->~basic_string();
    
    // after the lifetime of the object has ended and before the storage
    // which the object occupied is reused or released

    std::free(storage);

    // after the storage which the object occupied is released
}
```